# Highchart specific width stack column bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

Need to find a way to represent a graph with error bar, but it seems that it's not supporting in the `highchart` at the moment. My plan is to use a stack column bar chart with 0 to lower Y as transparent, and lower Y to upper Y with a red color or whatever I am gonna pick later.

My question is:

**Is it possible limit the stack column bar width to say 1px regardless the zoom level in highchart?**

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just figured out this myself.
pointWidth is the parameter to set the width for bar width.
Also the walk around is nice for represent the error bar since there aren't any highly interactive javascript chart support this type of chart yet.

Comment: can you share an example please?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! You should accept your answer as being correct.

Comment: That is awesome!
However, now my bars overlap each other. Did you have this problem? Or do you know how to auto-adjust the spacing between each bar?

Comment: **plotOptions.column.groupPadding** also has an effect on the column width. If a chart has many columns or no space to fit, the default 0.2 padding can distort the width. Setting it to 0 solves the problem.

Comment: @NitWitStudios Same problem. Found any solution?

Answer (score 25):

```
series: [{
            name: strSeriesTitle,
            data: arrData,
            pointWidth: 28
        }]
```

Answer (score 14):

[A working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/D9s3a/) for setting width of column bars irrespective of the chart size.

You will have to use `pointWidth` option like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 40//width of the column bars irrespective of the chart size
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: It is increasing the width of the `bars` but after that the `bars` are overlapping. I want to increase `bars` size respective of chart size. How?

Answer (score 10):

You should use the following options instead of `pointWidth` to be responsive and not fixed:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointPadding: 0, // Defaults to 0.1
        groupPadding: 0.01 // Defaults to 0.2
    }
},
```

Comment: Increase `groupPadding ` is very usefull for making a "secondary" minibar close to a bigger "principal" bar.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't want to use fixed pixels and pointWidth did not take a string percent. However, with pointPadding, groupPadding, and pointWidth, I don't see them documented. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series